# How to browse the iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, simulator

my app is creating a CSV file out of a db. I want to browse and open the file to test. How do I access the iphone simulator's storage ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All data of the Simulator is stored as local files on your Mac.

The path for the user data of iOS apps in the Simulator is:

> ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[OS version]/Applications/[appGUID]/

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to print out the location of where you store your file when you run the app in the simulator.

You can use this code to get the location of the Library/Cache folder here:

```
-(NSString *) mediaPathForFileName:(NSString *) fileName
{   
    NSArray *directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachesDirectory = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", cachesDirectory, fileName];

    return filePath;
}
```

Pass in a random file name like "test.txt":

```
// somewhere in your viewDidLoad method
[self mediaPathForFileName:@"test.txt"];
```

This will print out the path to your app Library/Cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

you need get the path of that file by using `NSLog` and then user `Shift+Cmd+G` to go to that path.

Answer (score 0):

pritn this path

NSArray *directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);